# HOW TO KEEP A FIXED HEADER ON TOP OF OTHER LAYERS?

Tags: header, sticky

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3RKr.png)

In this website i need to make header sticky Is there any way to make that sticky. I had tried this code. but header layer goes behind the all page content and not working properly even navigation button not clickable. please help me.thanks in advance.

.site-header-style-2 #header {

```
padding: 0;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
```

}